# Finding character pattern in IIS URL Rewrite rule

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

We have several blog posts that contain links (too many to change), that point to an old URL structure on our main website. The URLs contain several hyphens in them as the default separator.

Consider:

```
example.com/My-Awesome-Product
```

I need to write ALL urls that contain more than ONE hyphen, such as the above example, to:

```
example.com/Product/My-Awesome-Product
```

If the incoming url is:

```
example.com/Other-Page
```

...Then it shouldn't match.

Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?![^-]*-[^-]*$)^(.*\/)
```

Try this.replace with

```
$1Product/
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/4